# Storybook 5.3 issue with yarn version 2

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, storybook, yarnpkg-v2

For a project requirement, I am configuring storybook 5.3 for react component development. I am using Yarn version 2 as the package manager.I've done all the steps mentioned in the storybook [tutorial](https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-react/). but when starting the storybook using `'yarn storybook'`, it's showing below error. The same thing is working fine if I switch to npm. After reading some docs on 'yarn' I am assuming(maybe wrong) this is happening because of 'Plug'n'Play feature of Yarn. So any thoughts on how to fix this?.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/vimal/HDD/Development/Design/testspace/taskbox'
 @ multi ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js ./.yarn/cache/webpack-hot-middleware-npm-2.25.0-b59f3763d7-1.zip/node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true main[0]

ERROR in multi ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js ./.yarn/cache/webpack-hot-middleware-npm-2.25.0-b59f3763d7-1.zip/node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/vimal/HDD/Development/Design/testspace/taskbox'
 @ multi ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js ./.yarn/cache/webpack-hot-middleware-npm-2.25.0-b59f3763d7-1.zip/node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true main[1]

ERROR in multi ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js ./.yarn/cache/webpack-hot-middleware-npm-2.25.0-b59f3763d7-1.zip/node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/vimal/HDD/Development/Design/testspace/taskbox'
 @ multi ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js ./.yarn/cache/webpack-hot-middleware-npm-2.25.0-b59f3763d7-1.zip/node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true main[3]

ERROR in multi ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js ./.yarn/cache/webpack-hot-middleware-npm-2.25.0-b59f3763d7-1.zip/node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/vimal/HDD/Development/Design/testspace/taskbox'
 @ multi ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js ./.yarn/cache/webpack-hot-middleware-npm-2.25.0-b59f3763d7-1.zip/node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true main[2]

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/vimal/HDD/Development/Design/testspace/taskbox':
  Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/vimal/HDD/Development/Design/testspace/taskbox'
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/vimal/HDD/Development/Design/testspace/taskbox':
  Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/vimal/HDD/Development/Design/testspace/taskbox'

  - compiler.js:141 
    [html-webpack-plugin-npm-4.0.0-beta.5-9fc0a86688-1.zip]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:141:18

  - Compiler.js:343 
    [webpack-npm-4.41.5-ec6f53e9d3-1.zip]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:343:11

  - Compiler.js:681 
    [webpack-npm-4.41.5-ec6f53e9d3-1.zip]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:681:15


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [tapable-npm-1.1.3-f1c2843426-1.zip]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compiler.js:678 
    [webpack-npm-4.41.5-ec6f53e9d3-1.zip]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:678:31


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [tapable-npm-1.1.3-f1c2843426-1.zip]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1423 
    [webpack-npm-4.41.5-ec6f53e9d3-1.zip]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [tapable-npm-1.1.3-f1c2843426-1.zip]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1414 
    [webpack-npm-4.41.5-ec6f53e9d3-1.zip]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1414:32


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [tapable-npm-1.1.3-f1c2843426-1.zip]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1409 
    [webpack-npm-4.41.5-ec6f53e9d3-1.zip]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1409:36



Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
                          Asset     Size               Chunks  Chunk Names
    __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  536 KiB  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    [./.yarn/$$virtual/html-webpack-plugin-virtual-8c0fe702c5/0/cache/html-webpack-plugin-npm-4.0.0-beta.5-9fc0a86688-1.zip/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/templates/index.ejs] 2.15 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]
    [./.yarn/cache/lodash-npm-4.17.15-566d9324f7-1.zip/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 528 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]

    ERROR in ./.yarn/cache/lodash-npm-4.17.15-566d9324f7-1.zip/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/vimal/HDD/Development/Design/testspace/taskbox'
     @ ./.yarn/cache/lodash-npm-4.17.15-566d9324f7-1.zip/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 1:0-96
     @ ./.yarn/$$virtual/html-webpack-plugin-virtual-8c0fe702c5/0/cache/html-webpack-plugin-npm-4.0.0-beta.5-9fc0a86688-1.zip/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/templates/index.ejs

    ERROR in ./.yarn/cache/lodash-npm-4.17.15-566d9324f7-1.zip/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/vimal/HDD/Development/Design/testspace/taskbox'
     @ ./.yarn/cache/lodash-npm-4.17.15-566d9324f7-1.zip/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 1:0-96
     @ ./.yarn/$$virtual/html-webpack-plugin-virtual-8c0fe702c5/0/cache/html-webpack-plugin-npm-4.0.0-beta.5-9fc0a86688-1.zip/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./.yarn/$$virtual/@storybook-core-virtual-3f1196b7f0/0/cache/@storybook-core-npm-5.3.9-d2e9ade828-1.zip/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/templates/index.ejs

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
```

package.json looks like below

```
{
  "name": "Sbook",
  "scripts": {
    "storybook": "start-storybook"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.9",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using yarn workspaces and/or have your storybook project nested inside another project? I used to have a similar issue with lerna + yarn workspaces.

Comment: No, I am not using Lerna and yarn workspaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is actually caused because Storybook doesn't support Yarn 2 on versions older than v6.0.0 (still alpha at the time of this writing).

There is an issue regarding the status of supporting Yarn 2 [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9527#issuecomment-578426683)

I think the main issue here is that Yarn community rushed declaring Yarn 2 as stable version enforcing a very strict dependency resolution without a loose alternative leaving no time & space for the JS ecosystem to adjust.

[Here is a test repo](https://github.com/crubier/yarnv2-storybook) containing a step-by-step guide of the actions you need to take to install storybook with yarn 2. As a viable alternative that supports PnP and has similar CLI to NPM I would suggest PNPM

Comment: This has nothing to do with Yarn 2. I have Yarn 1.22 and it's working fine before and after version 6 of Storybook. This is more likely to happen if you have two competing versions of babel-loader as I did. Storybook 6 was pulling in babel-loader as was react-scripts but they were differing version. I tried adding the version of babel-loader pulled in by Storybook 6 to the dependency resolutions but that didn't do much. Ported my craco/react-script to webpack and that fixed it.